# Can a potential Supervisor leave a hint on you in the scholarships and influence somehow the selection?

Tags: thesis-committee

I wonder if a full time professor could somehow influence the scholarship committee. I know that my potential supervisor is currently recruiting PhD students, he told me when I first approached him. He has accepted to be my supervisor and we are in touch. How is he sure that he is gonna recruit the potential PhD students he has accepted to supervise? They may have 5 potential PhD students and none of them will get the scholarship.

Comment: So what is the point of a selection committee if it can be subverted like that?

Comment: I agree with you. The point is the section below. He cannot tell that “I am recruiting students” and not have a funding. This is the weird fact. You may like the students as a Supervisor but the scholarships committee no

Comment: He can certainly talk to the committee members or even write a formal letter to them to attract their attention to certain names, and if he has a good argument to put forth, he will, probably, be listened to, but since the final decision is not his, he can never be "sure", so any "guarantees" he might have promised you are essentially void.

Comment: The truth is that he never promised me something, to be honest. Just wondering how he is recruiting students without guaranteed funding.

Comment: But in general I don’t think that he would invest time in students he believes they have no chances of getting the scholarship even if he leaves a hint to the committee. I know that professors and especially the big names get a lot of requests. So thy have to be very picky, otherwise they are wasting their time.

Comment: @AmyMcDonald Are you sure the professor doesn't have a grant to fund students?

Comment: @BryanKrause I think he would have told me and I would be already in Australia, as I have already been admitted to the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that absent firm rules that professors lobby pretty hard for the students they most want. It isn't a question of leaving some subtle hint.

There might be rules against it, of course, and that might dampen it down a bit, but ....

There might even be "horse trading" among senior professors.

But it is just another form of competition. Having a professor strongly advocate for you doesn't guarantee much if other professors are lobbying for others and the money is limited.